# Update react ui after graphql mutation in node js

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I know if you make a mutation with graphql in the client side(react) you can use the refetchQueries to query the new updated list of (items) you have.

However if i were to make a mutation on node.js side, is it possible to update the ui after a mutation was made?

Comment: you're probably looking for `grpahQL subscriptions`

Comment: On the frontend you mean or backend?

Comment: both, it won't work if client wants to use sth not supported on server

Comment: The only thing im doing on the client side is to submit a form trough http, however the logic and mutation happens in the backend, and i think in this case the client wont know when these changes are done. I tried to query after the mutation on the backend but there was no visual change on the front-end

Comment: not much effrot on client needed, only have to subscribe - subscription opens and **keeps** connection (f.e. websocket) to update on changes - did you read docs? search for any graphql chat tutorial

Answer (score 0):

mutation function returns a `Promise` which when it resolves provides `data`:

```
SomeMutation({variables:{...}).then(data => ...)
```

also if you are using `Mutation` tag in react, the second parameter contains data, which updates automatically when you call the function. you can pass this as props to your component:

```
 <Mutation mutation={addServiceMutation}>
    {(addService, { data }) => ( ... )
 </Mutation>
```